# Animated splash screen in C#

Tags: c#, animated, dynamic-splash-screen

How can I have a Animated splash screen in C#

But I could still make a splash (Fixed)

```
private void SplashScreen()
{
    Application.Run(new Splash());
}
```

Comment: Looks like you are on the correct track. Your code suggest you have a form (view) by the name Splash. All you have to do is to apply your animation logic to Splash

Answer (score 0):

A few steps for WPF:

add a new window to your project and call it splash.

in the app.xaml remove the startupwindow, and register an event for startup.

in the app.xaml.cs add the following code.

```
    private void App_OnStartup(object sender, StartupEventArgs e)
    {
        var splash = new Splash();
        var mainwindow = new MainWindow();
        splash.ShowDialog();
        mainwindow.Show();
    }
```

Now the first window splash is opened and in that window you can do some animations.
After that window is closed (by the user or by using a timer and calling the close method.) the mainwindow will open.

A few notes you will have to set various properties in the splash window.

TopMost = true
StartupLocation = CenterScreen
WindowStyle = none

Play around with that window to get the desired effects.